# Hopfian and co-Hopfian groups

Tags: group-theory, hopfian, co-hopfian

Let $G$ be a group.
We say that $G$ is a Hopfian(Co-Hopfian) group, if every epimorphism(monomorphism) of $G$ if a monomorphism(epimorphism).
Can someone give me some applications of Hopfian and co-Hopfian groups in geometry...?

Answer (score 1):

Hopf was originally interested in surfaces, and maps between them. In his original paper$^{\dagger}$ he wrote,

> "I believe the problem of listing all classes of maps of the closed orientable surface of genus $g$ onto the closed orientable surface of genus $g$ is interesting, both on account of the connection with function-theoretical [analytic?] questions...as well as from a purely topological viewpoint. This question is only solved for special cases...Apart from these, it is easy to show that the sought-after list is identical to that of all homomorphisms of the fundamental group of the manifold into the fundamental group of the same manifold. However, this group-theoretic problem is most likely no easier to solve than the original geometric one." -- *Translated once upon a time by one of my German friends*.

---

$^{\dagger}$H. Hopf, *Beiträge zur Klassifizierung der Flachenabbildungen*, J. Reine Angew. Math., **165**, pp 225-236, 1931